# How can I get the compilation buffer on the bottom rather than on the right in Emacs 23?

Tags: emacs, buffer, emacs23

I've installed Emacs 23 and have found that the compilation buffer (when using M-x compile) appears in a different position than it did in Emacs 22. The currently open buffer appears on the left and the compilation buffer on the right. How to I revert to the Emacs 22 behavior of having the current buffer open on the top and the compilation buffer on the bottom?

(Splitting the screen horizontally also is the case for the buffer list (M-x switch-to-buffer <tab>) buffer as well.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's probably the new `split-window-preferred-function` variable and `split-window-sensibly` function.  Emacs now tries to figure out if it should split vertically or horizontally based on the window size (I assume you have a wide window).  Try setting the `split-width-threshold` variable to `nil`.

Comment: I only would like this for `*compilation*`.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked best for me:

```
;; Split windows in Emacs 22 compatible way
(setq split-height-threshold nil)
(setq split-width-threshold most-positive-fixnum)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in emacs 23 on linux :

```
(setq split-width-threshold most-positive-fixnum)
```