# Horizontal split for pop-to-buffer in Emacs 23?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a few scripts that use the function pop-to-buffer a lot. It used to split the window horizontally, but now in Emacs 23 it splits the window vertically. I've dug through some of the elisp code but it's not jumping out at me - how can I change this behavior of Emacs 23 to split horizontally again?

Comment: Same answer as this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966191/how-can-i-get-the-compilation-buffer-on-the-bottom-rather-than-on-the-right-in-em/

Comment: So true.  I've had trouble with SO's automatic finding of questions/answers.  I think I first learned of this from the answer you linked.  +1 to that answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's listed in the NEWS for Emacs (`C-h N`):

> *** `display-buffer' tries to be smarter when splitting windows. The
>   new option`
>   split-window-preferred-function' lets
>   you specify your own function to pop
>   up new windows.  Its default value
>   `split-window-sensibly' can split a
>   window either vertically or
>   horizontally, whichever seems more
>   suitable in the current configuration.
>   You can tune the behavior of
>   split-window-sensibly by customizing`
>   split-height-threshold' and the new
>   option `split-width-threshold'.  Both
>   options now take the value nil to
>   inhibit splitting in one direction. 
>   Setting split-width-threshold to nil
>   inhibits horizontal splitting and gets
>   you the behavior of Emacs 22 in this
>   respect.  In any case, display-buffer
>   may now split the largest window
>   vertically even when it is not as wide
>   as the containing frame.

I think what you want is:

```
(setq split-width-threshold nil)
```

(but I think you're using the vertical versus horizontal splitting the opposite of what Emacs terminology is (which **is** counterintuitive to me as well))

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to check there. And you're absolutely right about the terminology, both about me using it backwards (even though I know about the Emacs usage of it), and about it being counterintuitive!

Comment: The most useful part of this answer was the 'your doing it wrong' re what is vertical vs horizontal.